# How can i use default value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<td><input size="12" type="text" name="invoice[promcode][]" /></td>
    <td><input size="12" onchange='bitExtention(0)' id="itemname0" type="text" name="invoice[itemname][]"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="invoice[basecode][]"/></td>
    <td><input size="12" type="text" name="invoice[mm][]"/></td>
    <td><input onchange='bitExtention(0)' type="number" id="posotita0" name="invoice[quantity][]"/></td>
    <td><input onchange='bitExtention(0)' type="number" id="timi0" name="invoice[price][]" step="0.01"/></td>
    <td><input onchange='bitExtention(0)' type="number" id="discount0" name="invoice[discount][]" step="0.01"/></td>
    <td><input onchange='bitExtention(0)' type="number" id="sum0" name="invoice[sum][]" step="0.01"/></td>
    <td><input onchange='bitExtention(0)' type="number" id="foros0" name="invoice[tax][]" step="0.01"/></td>
```

i want to put a default value for each var like
`var timi = document.getElementById("timi"+x.toString()).defaultValue = 50;`
this seams to work but when i run the program i change the value to 100  but var timi dont get updated and stuck to 50

```
function bitExtention(x)
    {    
    var itemname = document.getElementById("itemname"+x.toString()).value;
    var test = JSON.parse('<%= raw Item.select('itemName','promCode','baseCode','monadaMe','price','fpa').collect { |p| [p.itemName, p.promCode, p.baseCode, p.monadaMe, p.price, p.fpa] }.join("\n").gsub("\n", " ").split(" ")%>');
    var dokimi = test.indexOf(itemname);
    var maura = test[dokimi+4];
    var posotita = document.getElementById("posotita"+x.toString()).value;
    var timi = document.getElementById("timi"+x.toString()).defaultValue = 50;
    var sum= document.getElementById("sum"+x.toString()).value;
        var fpa= document.getElementById("foros"+x.toString()).value;
        var discount= document.getElementById("discount"+x.toString()).value /100;
        var total = timi - (timi * discount);
    var total_foros = timi*fpa/100;
      sum = total * posotita + total_foros
      document.getElementById("sum"+x.toString()).value = sum;
}
```

i just notices tha the  0 || 50 works but it's no visibale at html table

fixed while puting this at the bottom of the code document.getElementById("timi"+x.toString()).value = timi; looks wrong but works for now

Comment: `var timi = doc...defaultValue = '50` your setting the `timi` identifier to 50, because it goes right to left `50` -> `defaultValue` -> `timi`, 50 is being streamed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

`let myVar = document.getElementById(...).value || "default value";`

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript default parameter](https://www.codereadability.com/javascript-default-parameters-with-or-operator/)

[Mozila mdn firefox for default parameter](https://www.codereadability.com/javascript-default-parameters-with-or-operator/)